# SQL date(timestamp) returns null value in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.stuff (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    -- a lot more columns here
    created_by int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified_by int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    modified_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    received_on date NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    CONSTRAINT pk_stuff PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create trigger tgr_update_modified_at before
update on public.stuff for each row execute function update_modified_at();
```

When I run `update stuff set received_on = date(created_at)` I get `ERROR: null value in column "received_on" violates not-null constraint` only for the following record:

```
select id, created_at, created_at::date as created_at_date, received_on
from stuff where id = 101408;

id      created_at          created_at_date received_on
101408  2020-11-13 10:11:51 2020-11-13      2020-11-13
```

When I exclude that record, the update query succeeds.
Why is it failing to update that record? What am I missing here?

UPDATE #1 The `update_modified_at()` is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_modified_at()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    if row (NEW.*) is distinct from row (OLD.*) then
        NEW.modified_at = now();
        return NEW;
    else
        return OLD;
    end if;
end;
$function$
;
```

UPDATE #2
In case it helps, this is the stacktrace of the exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "received_on" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (101408, ..., 100003, 2020-11-13 10:11:51.651373+01, 100003, 2020-11-13 10:13:42.372196+01, ..., null).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:327)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

As you can see for some reason `received_on` is indeed set to `null` (last value in the tuple).

UPDATE #3 I also tried the query in different tools, same error everywhere.

UPDATE #4 Just to be sure I'm not doing anything stupid;
when I run `update invoices set received_on = date(created_at)` on my table, it fails with the nullity error. But when I add `where id != 101408` (no other change at all, same db, same window, etc) the query succeeds (updated rows = 305). (See the record content above again.)

UPDATE #5 This is interesting. I can't even run `update stuff set received_on = current_date where id = 101408;` (fails with the same error). So it's not really about `date` function.

UPDATE #6 Something is fishy with this record, I can't update any other column of this record. `update stuff set another_column = 0 where id = 101408` fails with the same error (complaining about `received_on` can't be null).

UPDATE #7 I can fix the issue by running `update stuff set received_on = '2020-11-14' where id = 101408;`. After this everything works as expected. Interestingly, if I try to run `update stuff set received_on = '2020-11-13' where id = 101408;` (`2020-11-13` is the current value) instead of the previous query, it fails with the same error.

UPDATE #8 It happened again in a different table, different column while updating another column (simply trying to set it to `null`). One thing I noticed in both cases, the problematic columns are the one I added later (using `alter table`) and have `not null` constraint with some default value. Does this ring a bell?

Comment: Please provide the function `update_modified_at()` content. Look as it a root of problem

Comment: Added the DDL of the function.

Comment: that update can't throw that error if `created_at` is really defined as `NOT NULL`. Either your table definition in the database is not what you think it is, or you are running a different UPDATE statement (that uses a column other than `created_at`)

Comment: I'll re-run the query to make sure I didn't confuse. But I got the DDL queries from the SQL GUI (it's the same as our db migration scripts).

Comment: Confirmed. I can't run the update query, fails with the same error. Also, even if the DDL is wrong, the content of the record shows that `created_at` is not null. So not sure if DDL is relevant.

Comment: For this record with id 101408, your trigger will return old because the new value of received_on is the same as the existing value. Is this the only such record in your table? In other words, are you able to run the update query on other records where received_on is already equal to date(created_at)?

Comment: That's what I suspected at first. But seems not to be the case. Two reasons, even thought there's only one record with `date(created_at) == received_on` (`id = 101408`) in this table, I successfully managed to run the query on our dev env which has a couple of similar records. More than that, if that's the root cause, then I should not be able to re-run the update query on the same table twice (because for all records it's already `date(created_at) == received_on`). Same. no issue there. 

Comment: There most be something else, because your code is working just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e885d48d5f01f19d52f1023147b3e71 - do you maybe have your own `date()` function? What happens if you use the cast operator: `created_at::date`?

Comment: Same error with cast operator . You're right. It just works for everything except this record. I feel stupid, even if it's like one of the silly mistakes, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please see the last update.

Comment: Is there an index on the field or the table in general?

Comment: Not on that specific field, there's one index for PK and another for a UUID column in the table. See the last update.

Comment: Does update#8 ring a bell?